# INSERT into PostgreSQL table with unique columns and non-null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an existing table which I would like to alter in order for it to be such that col1 and col2 has to be unique if col3 has a non-null value.

So in the following example, the last row should fail to be inserted because the 4th row has the same col1 and col2 values with a non-null col3 value.

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| matt | 234 |  |
| matt | 234 |  |
| matt | 237 | banana |
| matt | 234 | apple |
| matt | 234 |  |
| matt | 234 | pear |

So how do I alter my table for it to account for col3's non-null values?
This is all that I have for now.

```
ALTER TABLE someTable
ADD UNIQUE (col1, col2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL didn't `UNIQUE` conditional constraint, however you can try to use [Partial Indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-partial.html) and add `UNIQUE`

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX someTable_unique_col1_col2 ON someTable(col1, col2)
WHERE col3 IS NOT NULL
```

[sqfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d4df9869cd78880ef0b2364f2af73630)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect.